# Can every function be a composite to itself and how to know if a composite between two functions is defined?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, function-and-relation-composition

Can every function be a composite to itself?

like we have $f:A\to B$ is $f \circ f$ always defined?

Can we say that if $f$ is a injection/surjection/bijection then so is $f\circ f$?

Also, how do we know if a composite between two functions is defined?

Comment: If $A \neq B$, the composition doesn't make sense - the function isn't defined on the target space.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why? also what if $A\subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$? @AlfredYerger

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$, then $f(x) = y, y \in B, y \notin A$. How do you define $f$ on this number when you apply $f$ again?

If $B \subseteq A$, then every value of B appears in A, so you're good. From here, you can check for injectivity, surjectivity or bijectivity as you would normally.

Comment: Also check out the concept of restrictions of a function.

Comment: @AlfredYerger by restrictions of a function you mean the two definitions for a function right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me take the standpoint of set theory, that a function is just a collection of ordered pairs with some special properties. (With the understanding that $f\colon A\to B$ means that the domain of $f$ is $A$ and its range is a subset of $B$.)

The composition of $f\circ f$ is indeed well-defined, and it will be a function, but it might be the empty function. The domain of $f\circ f$ will be, as it is easy to verify, $A\cap\operatorname{rng}(f)$, which may or may not be empty.

It is also quite easy to check that composing injective functions is again an injective function. However, when we say that a function is surjective, we make an appeal to an additional set, to $B$, so in order for the definition of "surjective" to make sense we need more than just $f$, rather we need $f\colon A\to B$, which will tell us non-trivial information about what $f$ is mapped *onto*, when we say it is a surjection.

Now $f\circ f$ isn't necessarily a function with domain $A$, and it's hard to say what exactly is its range, let alone when $f$ is some arbitrary function.

What is true, however, is that if $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ are surjective functions (and now we know that by surjective we mean that $\operatorname{rng}(f)=B$ and $\operatorname{rng}(g)=C$), then $g\circ f\colon A\to C$ is a surjective function (by which we mean that $\operatorname{rng}(g\circ f)=C$).

Comment: Thanks. BTW do you agree with what Alfred said about the subsets?